# Pdf of the difference between the maximum and minimum of uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let $\{X_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ independent random variables with uniform distribution in the
interval $[0,1]$. Let us denote by $\displaystyle U=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}X_{i}$ and $\displaystyle V=\min_{i=1,\ldots,n}X_{i}$ Let $W=U-V$, calculate $\mathbb{P}(0.3\leq W\leq 0.8)$.

Mi initial idea was define $A=\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2, u-v\leq w\}$ and use $\mathbb{P}(W\leq w)=\mathbb{P}((u,v)\in A)$, but $U$ and $V$ are not independent so I can't calculate the joint density function. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Let me get you started.  You want the density of arrangements for samples where one is the minimum (V), one is the maximum (U), and the rest are betwixt the twain.

$\qquad\begin{align}f_{U,V}(u,v) &= \tfrac{n!}{1!~(n-2)!~1!}~f_X(v)~\big(F_X(u)-F_X(v)\big)^{n-2}~f_X(u) \\&= n~(n-1)~(v-u)^{n-2}~\mathbf 1_{0\leq v\lt u\leq 1}\end{align}$

Answer (score 1):

If $\ 0\le v\le u\le1\ $ then
$$
\Bbb{P}(V\le v, U\le u)=\Bbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{X_i\le u\}\setminus\bigcap_{i=1}^n\{v<X_i\le u\}\right)\\
=u^n-(u-v)^n\ .
$$